# Error when trying to get OAuth Google SignIn to work in ejected expo project. I've tried everything

Tags: javascript, c, react-native, google-signin, expo

Okay, I know this issue has come up a ton so I’m just looking for a little direction since I’ve searched practically every thread and tried every solution to get this working. The app is created in create-react-native-app and uses a node.js backend and PGSQL server, not that any of that should matter… I have this function that is called on button press in my login component:

```
 _GoogleSignInAsync = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
          iosClientId: "717150291405-59od49j7rliuqt96n3v2dcc4gbkfhh37.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
        });

        if (result.type === 'success') {
          this.setState({
              signedIn: true,
              name: result.user.name,
              photoURL: result.user.photoUrl
          });
        } else {
          console.log("cancelled");
        }
      } catch(e) {
        console.log("error",e);
      }
}
```

which I copied from expo’s documentation. I then proceeded to “expo eject” my project because I saw that the error could be from expo not being able to connect to google’s API server in the first place (it's not native?). Which I predict might be true, because before I ejected the button would simply not do anything - now that it’s ejected and I’m running the simulator through XCode it throws an error:

```html
Exception 'You must specify |clientID| for |GIDSignIn|' was thrown 
while invoking 
logInAsync on target ExponentGoogle with params 
( behavior = system; scopes = ( profile, email ); [etc..]
```

My app.json looks like:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "nativesolemate",
    "description": "This project is really great.",
    "slug": "nativesolemate",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "SoleMateIOS",
      "publishBundlePath": "ios/nativesolemate/Supporting/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "ios/nativesolemate/Supporting/shell-app-manifest.json"
    },
    "isDetached": true,
    "detach": {
      "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.8.4-sdk30.0.0-3de13133-1adc-4ba1-8569-a84011e570b4.tar.gz",
      "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.8.1-sdk30.0.0-271c32ab-0715-4dfb-8270-ecead3679bb4.tar.gz"
    },
    "scheme": "exp64ed007d25db40ae8496b69aa354ab61",
    "android": {
      "package": "solemate.android.me",
      "publishBundlePath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app-manifest.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Here’s the real catch: on the google documentation for implementing this (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) it says to send your request in this way, keep in mind I don’t code in C, nor have I ever used CocoaPods:

```js
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application    
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";  
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;    
    return YES;
  }
```

So the closest thing in my compiled IOS files, I find a document labeled EXGoogle.m in Pods folder. I found the code:

```js
-(void)systemLogInWithIosClientId:(NSString *)clientId
                      webClientId:(NSString *)webClientId
                           scopes:(NSArray<NSString *> *)scopes
{
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"717150291405-59od49j7rliuqt96n3v2dcc4gbkfhh37.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  if (webClientId != nil) {
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = webClientId;
  }
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = scopes;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
  [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
}
```

Which seemed like where I was supposed to insert the ClientID I got form google although in the snippet I posted I went ahead and added the literal clientID, and before it was:

```js
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = clientID
```

I think I’m doing this right, but clearly I’m missing some reference point, don’t have some package installed, didn’t eject properly, or something. I hate to make y’all troubleshoot this but can someone give me a little headway?

Thanks x1,000,000 in advance, y’all